Civic Responsibility on London Railway regarding others tailgating us
So the wife and I just returned from a trip to London.  As every one suggested, we wisely did not rent a car and took the trains everywhere (including to and from Gatwick airport) using a CC or Apple pay for our fares.  It mostly worked out great, and certainly better than a rental car.
During one of our trips a man kind of rudely forced his way past us, which seems common, okay no big deal.  But then stopped when he got to the pay gate.  My wife went through one and I another.  He then got right behind my wife and went through with her so he did not have to pay.  We saw this a few other times with other people as the payer.
Would the UK authorities hold my wife, in our case responsible, for this man's behavior of not paying for his train fare?

I guess it’s not impossible that the person behind quickly tapped to pay using eg a smartwatch and as he was behind your wife/you, it was hard to see. The barriers likely have CCTV that would show fare dodging https://tfl.gov.uk/info-for/media/press-releases/2024/february/tfl-rolls-out-tougher-action-on-fare-evaders-and-staff-abuse-with-increased-penalty-fares-and-body-worn-cameras

@Traveller that did not happen in each of the situations I observed.

FWIW, having passed through London overground ticket barriers something of the order of 10,000 times, I've never experienced or witnessed that.  Unless things have changed drastically since the pandemic (or I've been improbably lucky), such things must be very rare!

It happens. I've been barged out of the way before when leaving a platform when I had put my ticket into the pay gate. I had to pay again to exit, and staff were unhelpful. Admittedly that was Leeds, and a fair while ago.

Happened to me once in Paris.  A woman followed uncomfortably close to me just before the gate.  I thought she was a pickpocket.  When I signaled her to keep some distance, she had a look like telling me how selfish I am.

Civic responsibility dictates that the correct response is to tut loudly, say "Do you mind?!" (optional), make eye contact with one or more of your fellow passengers (one of the few times this is allowed on the tube), and finish by shaking your head disgustedly. Thus all observers shall recognise and acknowledge your lack of complicity in the matter.

@Traveller London's rail network and especially the Underground is pretty well covered with CCTV, including inside the trains, with quite long retention of footage, and if their computer system picks up anomalies such as odd ticket usage or fake tickets they can track someone all the way from start to finish of a journey and come out and nab them at the end. Very often they agree to plead guilty when they see the video evidence. Example video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nymeucBFoNg

@gidds I think it depends on what part of London you live in. I don't think I'm near your 10k times but I've seen it happen loads

Speaking as a veteran of many decades' travel on TFL services, absolutely not.  If any offence has been committed, it's fare evasion by the man who entered/exited the network without the proper authorisation.
You don't say what kind of gate it was (underground, overground, Network Rail), but every interaction with these gates leaves an audit trail.  With contactless, your wife can show very quickly that her card was used to open a gate (revenue protection officers carry networked card-readers for this very purpose).  So should the question arise, she can prove beyond reasonable doubt that she'd paid the fare for her journey.  So there's just no way she could be held responsible for evasion on her own part.
As for culpability in the man's actions, there's no duty of care on the travelling public to prevent others from fare-dodging.  As long as she wasn't actively conspiring with the guy ("look, you come close behind me, I'll put my ticket in, and we'll both get through") she's done all that is required of a law-abiding citizen, and I'm sorry some scrote took advantage of her.  Revenue protection officers are usually highly experienced and have seen all kinds of evasion over the years; I'd be absolutely amazed if any interaction between revenue protection and your wife went past "Do you know this man?  No?  Thank you for your time, madam."

I kind of suspected this sort of answer and was on the lookout for this sort of thing after that as she is kind of small and could be knocked down.  Here if Florida the toll avoider might be shot by a private citizen for doing such.   This happened at the Stratford station as we used the Jubilee line to get to London and stayed at the Moxi.

Not defending fare evasion, but shooting someone for it does seem a tad excessive.

Maybe by "doing such" the OP meant knocking down his wife? (Shooting someone for knocking down your partner is still an overreaction but not as bad as shooting them for fare evasion ...)

@Traveller oh I agree, but I am not saying this wouldn't happen.  Even the UK fine is kind of light, only 100 if caught.

It's £100 (reduced to £50 for prompt payment) if they choose to give you a penalty fare.  If they choose to go to court, maximum fine is £1000 plus costs.

And, of course, if they choose to go to court, the prospect of a criminal conviction. TfL do tend to take a dim view of fare evaders.

Sadly we seem to have a system that sometimes puts harsh punishment on people who cooperate after evading, while doing little to address the hardcore evaders who utterly refuse to cooperate.

Tailgating out of a station doesn't necessarily mean fare evasion. National Rail and Interrail tickets are valid on the Elizabeth line but are not accepted at fare gates, so to exit you have to find a staff member or tailgate.

@PeteB. - £100 is the base fine; if you're found to have routinely evaded fares it can get much, much higher. One man who routinely evaded fares on a line I sometimes use was fined £10,000.

@PeteB. they might be shot in the same way as anyone might be shot for no reason in the US, right? You aren't saying that this murder would be in any way justified?

@terdon believe it or not, in some jurisdictions it would be classified as justified.  If you don't believe me search YouTube for Polk County Sheriff, he is one that encourages people to shoot criminals.

This is a question for legal.se, but are you really saying that a random citizen actually shooting a fare dodger dead could be legal, @PeteB.? Where there is no question of "stand your ground" (no attack, not the shooter's property/home) and no question of self defense, the victim wasn't posing any danger, they were just trying to avoid paying a fare?

Might I venture to suggest this conversation's gone a bit off-topic?  Unless anyone's a Transport for London Revenue Enforcement (Armed Sniper Division) Agent, it might be better to (as was suggested) post the question to Law.SE instead.

@MadHatter - that £100 reduced to £50 for prompt payment is not a 'fine' (only a court can issue those). It's a 'penalty fare' and may be asked for by a rail company if they accept that a mistake has been made, rather than an attempt to dodge a fare. If it is unpaid, the company will usually proceed to a Magistrate's Court summons, as it will at once for more serious cases. The result of a guilty verdict would be a criminal record, a real fine, a victim surcharge, and costs.

@MichaelHarvey I didn't say it was a fine; Pete B did.
